# Sqlite package not found C# visual studio

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, package, quick-install-package

I'm trying in my program to install the following install-package. I'm working with this program together with someone else. I installed this via a github link on my microsoft visual studio 2019.

What I want is to create a local database ( on my harddisk ).

The package I'm trying to install are:
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

This is the error that comes with the installing-package. The weird thing is that the computer we programmed this is working but not on mine. Even after uninstall Microsoft Visual studio 2019 / updating it. Can anybody help me what am I doing wrong?

***Install-Package : Project 'Default' is not found.
At line:1 char:1

- Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand***
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try with NuGet :

- Right clic in your project, **Manage NuGet packages**
- Left tab (browse), search and install :

> SQLite

> System.Data.SQLite.Core

Example of using :

```
sqlite_connexion = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFile + ";Version=3;");
sqlite_connexion.Open();

if (sqlite_connexion.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   {
        MessageBox.Show("Error database : " + Environment.NewLine + "Statut : " + sqlite_connexion.State);
        this.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm just looking on every file in my solution explorer but none of them has the option when I right click them to manage nugets.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/7n7q5ns/nuget1.jpg and 
https://i.ibb.co/0VKXjQP/nuget2.jpg

Comment: Thanks again but right click on any of my projects or maps in my solution won't show nuget is this something I need to install then?

Comment: Maybe you don't have the package.
- Open **Visual Studio Installer**
- Choose **Modify**
-Go to **Individual Components**
-Select **NuGet package manager**
-**Apply.**

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/RpqqZrq/1-visualstudioinstaller.jpg and https://i.ibb.co/3msFsRM/2-packages.jpg